# Python Distutils

Tags: python, mingw, distutils, cython

I was unable to install [cython](http://cython.org/) due to [strict version numbering class](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/distutils.version.StrictVersion-class.html) of [Distutils](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/dist/dist.html). For example binutils-2.18.50-20080109-2.tar.gz cannot be used along with [MinGW](http://mingw.org/) for installing cython. The [source code documentation](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/distutils.version.StrictVersion-class.html) says that "The rationale for this version numbering system will be explained in the distutils documentation." I am unable to find the rationale.

My question: What is the rationale for this version numbering system?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a very actionable question.  What would you do with the answer?  How would that fix your problem?  What would you like to do that you can't do?

Comment: The answer to this question will help me to understand and learn (a) design decisions and (b) why cython or any other similar library should depend on strict version numbering class of Distutils

Comment: I find the pythonxy distribution helpful (on Windows) http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/ (check downloads page for recent updates)

Answer (score 1):

That's just another stupidness of distutils. I personally remove this annoying check in my distutils installation on every windows machine I have to use.

Installing another mingw version would work as long as it passes the version check - but really, the whole idea of checking version of the tools does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this](http://www.develer.com/oss/GccWinBinaries) unofficial MinGW distribution, it has a simple install process that sets up distutils to use it for compiling extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the idea was to recommend that projects use a version number compatible with the StrictVersion class for easy sorting (i.e. comparison of versions, to know that 1.0 is newer than 1.0b).  The problem is that it never really took off, and the original author of distutils moved on to other projects.  When setuptools was started as a set of new features and monkey-patches to distutils, instead of using Version classes it defined an algorithm to convert any version number to a sortable representation.  A few years ago, Tarek Ziadé took over maintenance and development of distutils and worked on a PEP with the distutils community to define a new version number specification.  This PEP, PEP 386, has been accepted and implemented in distutils2.  It was defined with the goals of supporting features used by the community (alpha/beta/candidate versions, post-release markers for example) and still allow sorting.  It’s more constraining than the setuptools’ also, but much more useful than StrictVersion and LooseVersion.